# Does Rolemaster Unified Use Stat Checks?

Tags: rolemaster, rolemaster-unified

**Does Rolemaster Unified use stat checks?**

In other games, when something is dependent on only a statistic, there tend to be "Stat Checks". In such situations, you roll a check using the bonuses from the stat only. A very common example would be the classic  "Strength" check to see if you can lift a heavy object.

Is there something similar?

Answer (score 5):

**NO.  Use an appropriate skill check or Resistance Roll instead.**

Per jdale, a writer on the new ruleset.

> You mean rolling directly against your stat? No. You would make a maneuver against a skill, or perhaps an RR. Even feats of strength rely on a maneuver based on Weight Training skill, and fatigue is based on Body Development.

https://ironcrown.co.uk/ICEforums/index.php?topic=20363.msg237620#msg237620

Comment: Just a heads-up, the forum link doesn't work without logging in